# the earth is still round tomorrow or will be still round

Tags: modal-verbs, word-order, future-tense

Shall I say:

> The earth is still round tomorrow.

or

> The earth will be still round tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You would say the Earth **will be** still round tomorrow.  (Actually, the more idiomatic way to phrase it is "*will still be* round tomorrow".)

This is because you're making a statement or prediction about the future, and in a simple clause, we normally use *will* to do that.  We usually only use the present tense to describe the future when we're talking about something scheduled, like "I leave tomorrow at nine", but the nature of the Earth isn't something scheduled.

Reference: [talking about the future](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/talking-about-future)

Comment: I agree (hence my upvote). One caveat, though: we could get away with the first sentence if we were striving to speak in a philosophical or poetic tone. For example: _"Everything's going crazy around here! I just need to keep calm," Ted thought. "Remember, the earth is still round tomorrow," he assured himself._ However, this is an unusual usage that would not apply most of the time.

Comment: It's not germane to the question, but I can't be the only reader thinking: "But the Earth is not _round,_ it's _spherical,_ and even **that** is inaccurate, since it is demonstrably _oblate!_"

Comment: That means this is not a objective fact? That means I can say: "The earth which is known more by people will still be round tomorrow" right? Because we can use present tense to express future in relative clauses right?@J.R.

Comment: Of course it is an objective fact that the earth is round (or an oblate spheroid, *pace* @P.E.Dant) but I'm not sure how that affects what you're trying to say.  "The earth which is known more by people" doesn't really make sense.  Can you phrase it a different way?